# Calculating the response time of queries using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a set of queries which has to be executed simultaneously. For this I am starting a Runnable thread for each queries, calling it from a while loop iterating through the List of queries.

The thread executed each of the queries, and also calculates the time taken by each query to execute. This is done by capturing start time and end time getting the diff. This time should be specific for each query, which needs to be printed out along with the corresponding query/

In this scenario, do I just need to capture times and display? Will it lead to any synchronization problems?

Comment: You have to make sure that all the threads are done before you retrieve and display the times.

Comment: @BheshGurung so if I store the query along with the times somewhere, can I be assured that the time stored is will be for that query and not others? since I will be starting around 100 threads, there wouldnt be any overlap or sync probs yea?

Comment: I'm slightly confused: do you have one thread that executes all queries sequentially or do you start one individual thread for each query?

Comment: @Andreas_D i start an individual thread for each query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is too generic. Will it lead to concurrency problems? May be. Do you share Objects between each Runnable? If you do you MIGHT have issue, if you don't then no.

If your loop looks like this for example (this code proves a point - it does not work):

```
for(int i=0;i<queries.size();++i){
     String query = queries.get(i);
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Execute the query
        }
    });
}
```

Each Thread will execute it's own query WITHOUT accessing some shared data - then no, you will not have concurrency problems - at least in the Java code. You could have problems in the Database - for example multiple queries trying to update the same row.

Answer (score 1):

> In this scenario, do I just need to capture times and display? Will it
>   lead to any synchronization problems?

I don't know, do you?  Why don't you just have a member field for each one of your `Runnable` instances that keeps track of the time it takes to execute - and then when all threads are finished, iterate over the `Runnables` and display the data.  Who besides you knows what your true intentions are.  There are only two synchronization problems I know of: [Deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) & [Race](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) Conditions.  Neither one applies to this scenario.